# Why does this strcmp() syntax give me an error in mysql-5.7?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, strcmp

I was trying to test out the strcmp() function with strings
containing random email addresses in this SQL statement:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO possible_duplicate_email
-> (human_id, email_address_1, email_address_2, entry_date)
-> VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'bobyfischer@mymail.com', 
                                   'bobbyfischer@mymail.com')
-> WHERE ABS( STRCMP('bobbyrobin@mymail.com', 'bobyrobin@mymail.com') ) = 1;
```

Then I got this error message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
right syntax to use near 'WHERE ABS( STRCMP('bobbyrobin@mymail.com', 
'bobyrobin@mymail.com') ) = 1' at line 4
```

I've read the strcmp() documentation from the mysql-5.7 reference manual
and tried a simple SELECT statement to see that strcmp() returned a numeric
value ranging -1, 0, 1, which it did, and I've included the IGNORE option
to the SQL statement so as to proceed through errors. Could someone explain to me why I get this error when running strcmp() in the WHERE clause?

Comment: `INSERT` statements do **not** have a `WHERE` clause, unless doing an `INSERT ... SELECT` statement, then the `SELECT` portion of the query can use a `WHERE` clause. [See this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Paul T., the answer is:

INSERT statements do not have a WHERE clause, unless doing an INSERT ... SELECT statement, then the SELECT portion of the query can use a WHERE clause.